# What calculation would I have to use in order to have a parameter change three seperate columns on a side by side bar on TABLEAU

Tags: oracle, tableau-api

I need help getting all three graphs to change at the same time depending on if the parameter is on "idle" or "non-business" etc. In other words, one measure changing all three graphs at the same time. I don't know how to how to go about this. When I tried to apply what I had it just gave me one graph changing as I change it from "idle" to "non bus" etc. instead of three.

```
CASE [Parameter 7]
    WHEN 'Idle' 
        THEN [Idle % Phone Time]
    WHEN 'Idle' 
         THEN [Idle % Sched Time]
     WHEN 'Idle' 
         THEN [Idle % TTR Time]
     WHEN 'Non-Business'
         THEN [Non Bus % Phone Time]
     WHEN 'Non-Business' 
         THEN [Non Bus % Sched Time]
     WHEN 'Non-Business' 
        THEN [Non Bus % TTR Time]
     WHEN 'Non-Business or Idle' 
        THEN [Non Bus/Idle % Phone Time]
     WHEN 'Non-Business or Idle' 
        THEN [Non Bus % Sched Time]
     WHEN 'Non-Business or Idle'
        THEN [Non Bus/Idle % TTR Time]
     WHEN 'Business' 
        THEN [Bus % Phone Time]
     WHEN 'Business' 
        THEN [Bus % Sched Time]
    WHEN 'Business' 
        THEN [Bus % ttr]
END
```

Comment: Please clarify what is your goal?

Comment: I have a side by side bar graph in Tableau. It is 3 bars; Phone time, TTR Time, and Schedule Time. I want the bars to show the amount of "idle time" or "business time" in  total Phone time, Schedule Time, TTR Time Bar graph. Meaning that each "Phone TIme, or Schedule Time" Bar graph will change to show the % of time spent on Idle during their phone time.

Comment: My Question is, What Calculation would I have to use in order to have a parameter change three seperate coloumns.

Comment: Write 3 calculated fields that each reference the same parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
CASE
    WHEN  [Parameter 7] = 'Idle'  and xxxx = xxxx(about Phone_Time)
        THEN [Idle % Phone Time]
    WHEN [Parameter 7] = 'Idle' and xxxx = xxxx(about Sched_Time)
         THEN [Idle % Sched Time]
     WHEN [Parameter 7] = 'Idle' and xxxx = xxxx(about TTR_Time)
         THEN [Idle % TTR Time]
     WHEN  [Parameter 7] = 'Non-Business' and xxxx = xxxx(about Phone_Time)
         THEN [Non Bus % Phone Time]
     WHEN [Parameter 7] = 'Non-Business' and xxxx = xxxx(about Sched_Time)
         THEN [Non Bus % Sched Time]
     WHEN [Parameter 7] = 'Non-Business' and xxxx = xxxx(about TTR_Time)
        THEN [Non Bus % TTR Time]
     WHEN [Parameter 7] = 'Non-Business or Idle' and xxxx = xxxx(about Phone_Time)
        THEN [Non Bus/Idle % Phone Time]
     WHEN [Parameter 7] = 'Non-Business or Idle' and xxxx = xxxx(about Sched_Time)
        THEN [Non Bus % Sched Time]
     WHEN [Parameter 7] = 'Non-Business or Idle' and xxxx = xxxx(about TTR_Time)
        THEN [Non Bus/Idle % TTR Time]
     WHEN [Parameter 7] = 'Business' and xxxx = xxxx(about Phone_Time)
        THEN [Bus % Phone Time]
     WHEN [Parameter 7] = 'Business' and xxxx = xxxx(about Sched_Time)
        THEN [Bus % Sched Time]
    WHEN [Parameter 7] = 'Business' and xxxx = xxxx(about TTR _Time)
        THEN [Bus % ttr]
END as your_column_name
FROM your_table;
```

The xxxx=xxxx statement for determinative column to discriminate which condition means the row is Phone_Time, Sched_Time, TTR_Time)